# Running Hadoop Pi Example

Tags: java, hadoop

I need some help running Hadoop Pi example in Windows. I have sucecssfully setup Hadoop on Windows and can see all NameNode, SecondaryNameNode, JobTracker and TaskTracker running. I can also hit urls:

```
http://localhost:50070/, http://localhost:50030 and http://localhost:50090/.
```

However when I am trying to run the in-built Pi example I am getting following exception.

```
$ hadoop jar hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar pi 4 100
Not a valid JAR: C:\cygwin\home\chandeln\hadoop\hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar
```

I have also set both hadoop and java in my path.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

$ hadoop version
Hadoop 1.2.1
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152
Compiled by mattf on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
From source with checksum 6923c86528809c4e7e6f493b6b413a9a
This command was run using /C:/cygwin/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
```

My .bashrc looks like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Java/jdk1.7.0_40
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/cygdrive/c/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin
```

Can anybody shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though Hadoop is written in Java, it does not play well on Windows. If you really want to get up and running with Hadoop in the shortest possible time, I would recommend using Linux. You can download the free [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) application, and install it on Windows. Then, download the latest version on [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and install it as a virtual machine using VMWare Player. Then you can use your Ubuntu virtual machine to [install a single node cluster of Hadoop](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_4_4.html).

If this seems like too much work, open an [Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) account, and find [pre-configured Hadoop machines](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) to work with.

Comment: I installed Hadoop on Ubuntu and got it working and even got the Pi example working over there. However the only problem is that you have to type commands starting with "sudo" every now and then. Being a Windows developer all my life I don't understand when to execute command  starting with "sudo" and when not to.

Comment: @user2325154: Ensure that you own your Hadoop installation. If you do, you shouldn't have to use sudo. For example, if you downloaded Hadoop and extracted it using sudo, it will belong to root and you'll need to use sudo to access it. To ensure you are the owner, go to the directory with your Hadoop folder and type "sudo chown -R [your-username]:[your-groupname]", that will recursively give you ownership of the files and allow you to execute the commands without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely due to your Java version not matching with the Jar. Try with jdk1.6.

(Looks like you are playing with YDN Hadoop?)

Answer (score 0):

try
$yarn jar hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar pi 4 100